# Hugo github actions 404

Tags: github-pages, github-actions, hugo

I have a very minimal github actions yml and have mostly set everything to default values. The only difference is that in my `config.yml` of the website, I have my `baseURL` set to `https://<username>.github.io/`.

```
name: github pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true  # Fetch Hugo themes (true OR recursive)
          fetch-depth: 0    # Fetch all history for .GitInfo and .Lastmod

      - name: Setup Hugo
        uses: peaceiris/actions-hugo@v2
        with:
          hugo-version: 'latest'

      - name: Build
        run: hugo

      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./public
```

The actions all pass, and it says that my page has been deployed, but when I try to access my page (`https://<username>.github.io`) I get a 404 page not found error. My `config.yml` is basically:

```
baseURL: "https://<username>.github.io/"
disablePathToLower: true
languageCode: en
```

What's wrong here? Could anyone please help? The site builds fine locally and I can see it on my localhost with no issues.

[Github Actions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2ySp.png)

Comment: I can see if I can help since I use this actionns myself.  By default, the page is deployed to `gh-pages` branch. Do you have that set-up in the settings or do you have `main`? See this page about first deployment using a `github_token` approach; https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#%EF%B8%8F-first-deployment-with-github_token

Comment: I have it deploying out of `master` at the moment as it says on my actions yml; does that mean I have to create a separate `gh-pages` branch or point the action toward gh-pages??

Comment: The default settings is to do `gh-pages` branch and it creates that branch if it doesn't exist. You don't need to point anything, just update your settings for the repository that is described on that link I provided.